# Eigenvalues of a blockmatrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, block-matrices

I am very interested in finding the eigenvalues of the matrix $\bf{A}$ below, which consists of $4$ block matrices of the same size $n \times n$ ,
$
\textbf{A}=\begin{pmatrix} {\bf{A}}_1 & {\bf{A}}_2 \\ {\bf{A}}_3 & {\bf{A}}_4 \end{pmatrix}
$, with ${\bf{A}}_2=({\bf{A}}_3)^T$, where no entry is equal to $\bf{0}$ (matrix with only zeros as its entries). The matrices are allowed to have complex entries.
Furthermore following relations hold true:

$$ \begin{aligned} {\bf A}_1 &= {\bf B}_1^T {\bf B}_1 + {\bf B}_2^T {\bf B}_2\\ {\bf A}_2 &= {\bf B}_2^T {\bf B}_3\\
{\bf A}_3 &= {\bf B}_3^T {\bf B}_2\\
{\bf A}_4 &= {\bf B}_3^T {\bf B}_3 \end{aligned} $$

I know that the determinant of this matrix $\bf{A}$  is obtained as

$$ \det({\bf{A}} ) = \det({\bf{A}}_1) \det \left({\bf{A}}_4-{\bf{A}}_3{\bf{A}}_1^{-1}{\bf{A}}_2 \right),$$

however I do not know how I would compute the eigenvalues of this matrix ${\bf{A}}.$ I am thinking of using:

$$ \det(\textbf{A}_1-\lambda \textbf{I}) \det(\textbf{A}_4-\lambda \textbf{I} - \textbf{A}_3 (\textbf{A}_1-\lambda \textbf{I})^{-1} \textbf{A}_2) = 0 $$

However, could I analytically solve for $\lambda$? Can anyone please provide me with some advice? I would highly appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: The trace of $A$ is the sum of traces of $A_1$ and $A_4.$ The factorisation of the determinant $det(M)=det(A_1)det(sA_1)=det(A_4)det(sA_4),$ where  $sA_i$ denotes the Schur complement od the related matrix (if it is invertible). But it is not enough if $n$ is large. Do you have more information about the matrices? Do some of them commute? Do they have further special properties?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment!

A2 und A4 seem very similar, you can define A2 and A3 as:
$
A2=C^{T} D
$ 
and $A3=D^{T} C$.
Furthermore $A4=D^{T} D$.
$n$ in my case is indeed large.
I hope these information  are useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your repsonse!
Indeed, $A2=(A3)^T$, I did not notice it right away. However I do not see how then $A2=A3$ holds true, can you elaborate on that, especially for the case when the entries $A_i$ are allowed to be complex. Do you also know how I would be able to derive an analytical expression for the eigenvalues?

Comment: Thank you once more, for your reply! I highly appreciate it!
Sorry, I guess I was not precise in my formulation. 
The four matrices are not symmetrical unfortunately. 
Is there a general way to solve my problem?
$det(\textbf{A}_1-\lambda \textbf{I})det(\textbf{A}_4-\lambda \textbf{I}-\textbf{A}_3 (\textbf{A}_1-\lambda \textbf{I})^{-1} \textbf{A}_2)=0$
Is it possible to use some matrix norms in order to simplify this equation?

Comment: I opened the bounty on your question :-) Hope it will help. I am interested in relevant answers as well. I find the problem too large, more information from your side would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I am very thankful for your help so far :D !
It is a rather large problem, maybe this can provide some further insights:
$\textbf{A}_1=\textbf{B}_1^T \textbf{B}_1+\textbf{B}_2^T \textbf{B}_2\\
\textbf{A}_2=\textbf{B}_2^T \textbf{B}_3\\
\textbf{A}_3=\textbf{B}_3^T \textbf{B}_2\\
\textbf{A}_4=\textbf{B}_3^T \textbf{B}_3\\
$
I would like to solve for $\lambda$, which would represent the eigenvalue of the matrix $\textbf{A}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for opening the bounty on my question!!

Comment: I´ve edited my answer linking a related question on mathoverflow.

Comment: The difficulty here is that there is no solution to your problem because the assumptions that you have do impose too much structure on the problem. It is also unclear what you are looking for. Closed-form or analytical solutions do not exist in this case. The expressions that you got are petty much the best you can get. If you want more, then you will have to put more assumptions or even numerical values. But even there, it is unlikely that you will get analytical solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I come up with a partial solution.
First, let us simplify notation settings
$${\bf{B}}={\bf{B}}_1, {\bf{C}}={\bf{B}}_2,{\bf{D}}={\bf{B}}_3.$$
The matrix is
$${\bf{A}}=\begin{pmatrix}{\bf{B}}^T{\bf{B}}+{\bf{C}}^T{\bf{C}} & {\bf{C}}^T{\bf{D}} \\ {\bf{D}}^T{\bf{C}} & {\bf{D}}^T{\bf{D}} \end{pmatrix},$$
which is nothing but a product
$${\bf{A}}=\begin{pmatrix}{\bf{C}}^T & {\bf{B}}^T \\ {\bf{D}}^T & \bf{0} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} {\bf{C}} & {\bf{D}} \\ {\bf{B}} & \bf{0}\end{pmatrix}:={\bf{M}}^T{\bf{M}}$$
The two matrices are transpose to each other, hence they have equal determinants.
The determinant is
$$\text{det}({\bf{A}})=\text{det}({\bf{M}})^2=\Big(\text{det}({\bf{C}})\;\text{det}\left(-{\bf{B}}{\bf{C}}^{-1}{\bf{D}} \right)\Big)^2=\Big(\text{det}({\bf{B}})\;\text{det}({\bf{D}}) \Big)^2$$
This result fits with the fact that the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} {\bf{C}} & {\bf{D}} \\ {\bf{B}} & \bf{0}\end{pmatrix}$ is anti-triangular.

NOTE
If you can provide more details about the matrices, we could find even more.

---

**EDIT**
The matrix can also be written with the use of transpose triangular block matrices: $${\bf{A}}=\begin{pmatrix}{\bf{B}}^T & {\bf{C}}^T \\ \bf{0} & {\bf{D}}^T  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} {\bf{B}} & {\bf{0}} \\ {\bf{C}} & \bf{D}\end{pmatrix}:={\bf{\Omega}}^T{\bf{\Omega}}$$
Eigenvalues of $\bf{A}$ are singular values of ${\bf{\Omega}}^T$ or ${\bf{\Omega}}.$ In [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265887/bounding-the-minimum-singular-value-of-a-block-triangular-matrix) is their matrix $M$ equal to my ${\bf{\Omega}}^T$ except the names of blocks.
This is a next small step towards a solution you are looking for.